# If I try to preview a previous revision of an entry, I get "an unknown error occurred"

Tags: error, bug, entry-versions, preview

Craft 3.3.15

Previous version of the entry was saved 1 minute ago, so no changes in settings between the two entries.

Any ideas on how to debug this?

Update - here's the error, which looks very much like what @mtnorthrop is getting:

```
2019-11-20 10:41:44 [-][1][-][error][TypeError] TypeError: Argument 1 passed to craft\helpers\ElementHelper::isTempSlug() must be of the type string, null given, called in /Users/andrei/Desktop/dev/hl/mailbuilder/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/EntryRevisionsController.php on line 473 and defined in /Users/andrei/Desktop/dev/hl/mailbuilder/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/ElementHelper.php:47
```

Comment: Check your Craft `storage/logs` files for `[error]` - that should contain the underlying error message for the "unknown error" flash message.

Comment: I've also experienced this issue. The logs report: TypeError: Argument 1 passed to craft\helpers\ElementHelper::isTempSlug() must be of the type string, null given, called in /vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/EntryRevisionsController.php on line 473 and defined in /vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/ElementHelper.php:47

Comment: @mtnorthrop did you find a solution?

Comment: This was a bug in Craft that's been fixed as of Craft 3.3.16: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG-v3.md#3316---2019-11-22 Going to go ahead and vote to close this as a bug report.

Comment: @aaandre I can confirm that updating to Craft 3.3.16.1 fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug was due to an issue with the Stringify library and was fixed in Craft 3.3.16.1, as stated by Brad Bell in his comment on the original question.

Upgrading to Craft 3.3.16.1 fixes this issue.

(I'm posting this as an answer in case anybody else runs into the same issue.)

Comment: The upgrade fixed the issue for me, too